# Iterating through a list in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to iterate through a list and take each part of the list, encode it and join the result up when it is all done.  As an example, I have a string which produces a list with each element being 16 characters in length.

```
message = (u'sixteen-letters.sixteen-letters.sixteen-letters.sixteen-letters.')
result = split16(message, 16)
msg = ';'.join(encode(result.pop(0)) for i in result)
```

The encode function takes a 16 byte string and returns the result. However with the way it is written, it only encodes half of the elements in the list.

If I try comprehension:

```
result = [encode(split16(message, 16) for message in list_of_messages)]
result = ''.join(result)
```

It results in the whole list being sent at once.  What I need to do is send each element to the encode function separately, get the result then join them together.

Is there an easy way of achieving this?

Comment: your list comprehension is syntactically wrong

Comment: Thanks SilentGhost, tested your code and works perfectly.

Comment: @rescue: Don't comment on your own question.  Please fix your question to have the correct code.

Comment: "The encode function takes a 16 byte string" - don't you mean 16 char string? 1 char is not necessarily 1 byte, especially since you are using unicode strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
';'.join(encode(i) for i in message.split('.'))
```

of course it could be just

```
';'.join(encode(i) for i in result)
```

if your `split16` function complicated enough.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused about what you are exactly trying to do, which is compounded by a missing paren in the code you posted:

```
result = [encode(split16(message, 16) for message in list_of_messages]
```

Should that be:

```
result = [encode(split16(message, 16) for message in list_of_messages)]
```

or:

```
result = [encode(split16(message, 16)) for message in list_of_messages]
```

I think the second will do what you want.

This code:

```
msg = ';'.join(encode(result.pop(0)) for i in result)
```

is failing because at every step you are iterating through `result`, but shortening it at every step with `pop`.  It should just be:

```
msg = ';'.join(encode(i) for i in result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear what you are after, but

```
msg=";".join(map(encode,(message[i:i+16] for i in range(0,len(message),16))))
```