# Decoding a list of encoded strings

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

I am working on a publication dataset, and after extracting data from a xml file, I got a list of this kind:

```
['21-10-2013', ['título do artigo'],['álvaro', 'joão', 'márcio'],['teste', 'operação','manobras']]
```

As you can see the words are in portuguese. In order to convert to unicode I tried a code from Kumar McMillan, I got in farmdev.com/talks/unicode/. Here is the code:

```
>>> def to_unicode_or_bust(obj, encoding='utf-8'):
...     if isinstance(obj, basestring):
...         if not isinstance(obj, unicode):
...             obj = unicode(obj, encoding)
...     return obj
...
```

I tried the code in a simple string:
    ab= "trabalhar com a imaginação"

The output:

```
>>> cd=to_unicode_or_bust(ab)
u'trabalhar com a imagina\xe7\xe3o'
```

If I issue the print command:

```
>>> print cd
trabalhar com a imaginação
```

Ok, that seems all right. But how can I apply to the list?
Naïve try:

```
>>> lista2 = to_unicode_or_bust(lista1)
>>> print lista2
['21-10-2013', ['t\xc3\xadtulo do artigo'], ['\xc3\xa1lvaro', 'jo\xc3\xa3o', 'm\xc3\xa1rcio'], ['teste', 'opera\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o', 'manobras']]
```

May be it's a newbie question, I know, but what should I do in order to get the correct portuguese characters in lista2?

Comment: Seems to be working properly to me.  Try recursing through the list and printing the actual strings...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating through a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571651/iterating-through-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Use a loop, or a list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you, Frankie, but observe that the output of print is not correct: it should be ['21-10-2013',['título do artigo'],['álvaro', 'joão', 'marcio'], ['teste', 'operação', 'manobras']]. So, how print could work when the list items are coded in utf-8 and should be rendered as unicode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you have is just fine, but it only works on a single string at a time - if it's passed something other than a non-unicode string, it just returns it. You're passing it a `list` and it comes back to you unchanged.

This recursive function should go through every bit and reassemble it with the converted strings.

```
def convert_all(all, convert=to_unicode_or_bust):
    if isinstance(all, tuple):
        return tuple(convert_all(piece, convert) for piece in all)
    elif isinstance(all, list):
        return [convert_all(piece, convert) for piece in all]
    return convert(all)
```

Be aware that when you print a `list`, the strings within the list will have Unicode characters shown with a `\x--` or `\u----` format, but the individual strings will print correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I will use your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

if you have string itself you can use the following syntax:

```
mystring = u'سلام'
```

if you don't have u'' python ignore unicode base.

But print command: you should use :

```
print str.decode('utf-8')
```

your variables:

```
mystring = unicode(myvar)
```